# ReportLab Scale Canvas after Drawing (Fit to Page)

Tags: python, pdf, canvas, reportlab

With the Python ReportLab library's `canvas`, the paradigm seems to be to apply transforms *before* drawing your primitives.

My desire is to scale what I've already drawn to fit the page size.

The problem is that I cannot know the extents of the drawn objects until I have drawn it entirely. This is because the input for drawing objects is a stream, which does not expose the maximum extents beforehand.

Right now, I have to:

- Draw my objects
- Check their extents
- In a new canvas, set the scale to fit the extents to the page size
- Draw objects again

In some cases, the object drawing can take a few seconds. And doing this twice really feels burdensome.

Is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: Have you tried drawing on a Form XObject instead of a page and then scaling it for the destination page?